# entity framework 6 vs core

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm still struggling to decide whether to use EF6 or core for my small business management system I'm going to create in VB net. I've already created an SQL database that has about 100 tables and the data won't be very intensive. I've read that core doesn't support model first but I've also read that it's possible to do code first that's based on an existing database. (didn't really understand that but I'll research it if I decide to go core).

A few months ago I was determined that I'd just stick to v6 which has been around forever, most popular, and probably has all the functionality I'd ever need for my small business and won't be going anywhere in the near future.

But now I see core.2 came out and I understand that since core was build from the ground up, MS has a special interest in developing it to be the best EF out there. I have a feeling that although v6 won't be going anywhere soon, that MS will be putting most of there effort into core with each new version and of course, you can always upgrade to newer versions but as I understood, will never be able to convert a project from v6 to core. So I feel like I'd regret starting with v6 and being stuck with it and missing out on the "core-train".

What do you think?

Comment: The problem is that EF Core is still in development, has many bugs and lacks many things. Read carefully [Which One Is Right for You](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/choosing).

Comment: <opinion expiration='2017-09-01'> You'll be most productive right now with EF6 Code First from Existing Database.  So unless you're targeting .NET Core, stick with EF 6 for now.</opinion>

Comment: David, I agree with your comment and decided to go with 6. If you write your comment as an answer, I can accept it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The EntityFrameworkCore is not mature now, we have met lots of issues. So you should wait for 3.0 if you want to use it in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a feeling that although v6 won't be going anywhere soon

I believe you are right here. Microsoft may add some fixes on `EF6` but they will probably not do any heavy development here since they will put their effort on `EF Core`.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Classic](http://entityframework-classic.net/)

Entity Framework Classic is a supported version from the latest EF6 code base. It supports .NET Framework and .NET Core and overcomes some EF limitations by adding tons of must-haves built-in features.

There is a Community Version (Free) and Enterprise Version (Paid).

As being the owner of several EF library such as `Entity Framework Extensions`, `Entity Framework Plus`, `EF Dynamic Filter`, `EF Effort`, `EF Graph Diff`, and more. You can expect this library to have some ongoing development.